# How to open <ace:dialog> or <p:dialog> by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, dialog, primefaces, icefaces-3

I need to open ace:dialog or p:dialog (because IceFaces is a fork of PrimeFaces, and it's the same tag and attributes) in area where I've did the click with the mouse, but I don't know how to do this with JavaScript. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

General: To open the dialog just call onclick="mydialog.show();" on the html element where the click should be possible..

If you want to show the dialog at the "click-position", maybe you should write your own javascript method to set the position..

Or easier, use the property "onShow" of the dialog to set the "position", which is also a property of the dialog.

Have a look here..
http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dialog.html